# Android - how do I run a server socket that receives data randomly forever?

Tags: java, android

So I am new to programing on android, and a bit rusty when it comes to java coding. What I am trying to do is make a service that runs constantly that also runs a listening port constantly so at any time of the day I can ping it and send a string to it from a pc.

I have code that I mashed together and it seems to work for about 30 minutes then it completely stops listening. What are the different solutions to solve this problem head on?

Btw the code is very sloppy as I frankensteined a bunch of code together without cleaning it up.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class PortListening extends Service {
    public PortListening() {
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        onTaskRemoved(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new server().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
        startService(restartServiceIntent);
        new server().execute();
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    class server extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed
        }
        
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d("Test", "onHandleIntent");
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
            wakeLock.acquire();
                final int port = 43001;
                ServerSocket listener = null;
                try {
                    listener = new ServerSocket(port);
                    Log.d("Test", String.format("listening on port = %d", port));
                    while (true) {
                        Socket socket = listener.accept();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        for (String inputLine; (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
                            boolean permissionGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                            if (permissionGranted) {
                                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                sms.sendTextMessage("+1 3**-6**-0***", null, inputLine, null, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Test", e.toString());
                }
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to make it a foreground service.

Comment: Try to make a constant notification so that android doesn' kill your program. Or probably use ``Thread`` and ``Handler`` instead of ``AsyncTask``.

Answer (score 0):

Making the service a foreground service has seem to fix my issue, thanks @[blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) for the suggestion.

With the code running as a foreground service the user is notified that the service is running, it also prevents the code from being killed when the system goes to purge running services that are background while the device is not actively being used.